# How would I make this loop until the user enters a blank line in java?

Tags: java, stack, palindrome

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class PalindromeTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

           System.out.print("Enter any string:");
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           String inputString = in.nextLine();
           Queue queue = new LinkedList();
           for (int i = inputString.length()-1; i >=0; i--) 
           {
               queue.add(inputString.charAt(i));
           }

           String reverseString = "";

           while (!queue.isEmpty()) 
           {
               reverseString = reverseString+queue.remove();
           }
           if (inputString.equals(reverseString))
              System.out.println("The input String is a palindrome.");
           else
              System.out.println("The input String is not a palindrome.");
    }
}
```

So this code prints out if the string input is a Palindrome, but not sure how to make it so it loops and terminates when a blank line is entered. I've tried a do while loop but had no luck

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe?

```
        System.out.print("Enter any string:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString; //extract the inputString as a variable
        while (!(inputString = in.nextLine()).equals("")) //just add this loop, the rest is same as yours
        {
            Queue queue = new LinkedList();
            for (int i = inputString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                queue.add(inputString.charAt(i));
            }

            String reverseString = "";

            while (!queue.isEmpty())
            {
                reverseString = reverseString + queue.remove();
            }
            if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(reverseString))
            {
                System.out.println("The input String is a palindrome.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The input String is not a palindrome.");
            }
            System.out.print("Enter any string:");
        }
```

Comment: So try modifying this ?
 String inputString; while (!(inputString = in.nextLine()).equals(""))

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking now.

Comment: Where exactly is your change at? Oh I see the code block now. Sorry

Comment: Just added one loop, everything is same as yours. I added a comment

Comment: ok it works, but the Enter any string: doesn't show up. Maybe I should add a System.out.println in the loop :]! Thank you sir

Comment: Yes, you are right, you should add it to the end of the while loop. Please consider accepting the answer if it works.

Comment: Done, works amazingly well. Thank you so much. One small concern, when i type Dad and dad, they show up as different things. is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: Yes, instad of inputString.equals(reverseString) use inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(reverseString).